# What is the difference between knockoutjs 2.x and 3.0.0

Tags: knockout.js

What is the main difference between knockoutjs 2.x and 3.0.0 ?
What had been improved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is great screencast by Ryan Niemeyer:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/10/knockout-3-highlights.html